# Is there a way to stack models trained with different data sets with the stacks package in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, stack, tidymodels, ensemble-learning

Briefly, I am working with data sets from two different countries. My aim is to ensemble the models for both countries to see how generalizable the ensemble becomes

My set-up is: I have trained one worfklow_set for each country (10 model specifications with resampling and a grid search of size 20).

This is the error I get when trying to add them as candidates:

```
predictions <- stacks() %>% 
  add_candidates(wf_set_1) %>% 
  add_candidates(wf_set_2)
```

> Error:
> It seems like the new candidate member 'Logistic Regression' doesn't make use of the same resampling object as the existing candidates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the question!

Unfortunately, we don't support ensembling models trained on different data sets in stacks. There are a few operations that are no longer well-defined when this is the case.

Given your description of the problem, though, this sounds like a setting where, rather than fitting a model for each country, the country would be included as a feature in one model that fits across countries. For any covariates `x_i` whose effect you feel may be dependent on country, you can create an interaction term with `step_interact(x_i, country)`.